# how can i filter multiple records in another assosiated table in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to write a filter system in ruby on rails.

I have a table with this information:

```
Tool.create(name: 'Confluence', image: 'confluence.png')
Tool.create(name: 'Git', image: 'git.png')
Tool.create(name: 'JIRA Core', image: 'jira-core.png')
Tool.create(name: 'JIRA Software', image: 'jira-software.png')
```

And then I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with my `User` table

I want to be able so search for people that have been associated with multiple tools.

So in my code using:

```
if params["Confluence"]
  contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where(tools: { name: "Confluence"})
end
```

I can search through the databases and return data for one search but if i then try and use another thing like:

```
if params["JIRA Core"]
  contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where( tools: {name: "JIRA Core"})
end
```

I no longer get any results even though i have data that should reflect this in my database.

If anyone knows where i'm going wrong i will be really grateful.

Comment: to clarify contractors is coming from User.all

Comment: what is the value of `contractors ` before `params["JIRA Core"]` ? add the output of `contractors ` in the question.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i filter through and find users that have User.tool.name = "Confluence" as well as the other recrods that have User.tool.name = "JIRA Core" and so on

Comment: Awlad Liton , it is still and object of users for instance  #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2016-11-04 16:26:23", updated_at: "2016-11-07 09:49:37", first_name: "Nick", last_name: "noone", phone_number: "(412) 85478", country_id: 1, contractor_tagline: "Experienced Full-Stack Atlassian DevOps Admin", contractor_about_me: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not sim...", contractor_image: "profile.png", contractor_city: "Eugene", contractor_state: "OR", contractor_zip: "97405", distance_willing_to_travel_in_miles: 200,

Comment: Can you run the second conditions statement in debug mode? it should give us sql by the `to_sql`

Comment: Are these conditionals one after the other or is the second a replacement of the first? If this is the former are you sure you have contractors that have both "Confluence" and "JIRA Core" since you would be reassigning contractors?

Comment: yes they are straight after each other, i have it above so that it does through other filters and at the end whatever is left from all users is what is bought back. there are multiple users with both confulence and jira core